# Cross referencing the Fig.1 and Eq.(1) in blue color in \documentclass{elsarticle}

Tags: cross-referencing, elsarticle

please tell me the necessary packages that I must use to get blue colored cross-referring to Fig.1 and Eq.(1). I want to change the color of Fig.1 from black to blue. Thank you very much in advance.

```
\documentclass[5p]{elsarticle}


\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\usepackage{times}


\begin{document}


%\linenumbers

\section{Introduction}
Piezoelectric Fig.1 and Eq.(1) effect has been employed to a very great extent in many applications since its discovery by the Curie brothers.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, please tell me the necessary packages that I must use to get blue colored cross-referring to Fig.1 and Eq.(1).  I want to change the color of Fig.1 from black to blue. Thank you very much in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you only need to add the hyperref package. The setup commands also needed are:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks   = true,
        citecolor    = blue
    }
```

Comment: If I use this code, I get the blue colored number when I cross-refer the Figures and  Tables but the word Fig. and Table.  is still in black color. Thank you

Comment: Hi, @Prakash try using \autoref{} instead of \ref{}. So you do not need to put Fig. or Table.